# Server-side joining for socket.io's namespaces

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

As the socket.io docs says, you can join to a `namespace` using this code in the client script:

```
io.connect('http://localhost');
```

As far as I know, a method for adding a socket to a `namespace` in the server isn't provided, but I was able to add a socket to a `namespace` (in the server) using code similar to the following:

```
socket.join('somenamespace');
io.of('somenamespace').emit('some-message', { ... });
```

After the execution of the second line, the `connection` event for `'somenamespace'` is triggered.

Why does this happens? is it correct to use this approach for adding a socket to a namespace in the server side?

Is there any *correct* way for adding a socket to a `namespace` in the **server** side?

As a note, I'm using `socket.io 0.9.14` and `sails 0.9.8`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way for adding socket to `namespaces`. If you have defined namespaces in your server as:

```
var namespace1 = io.of('/namespace1');
namespace1.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('msg',"message"); //only the particular socket from /namespace1 will get
});
  //If you do this
namespace1.emit('msgToAll', "message"); //everyone in namespace1 will get this message
```

However, rooms are different than namespaces.
And you can connect to a particular namespace from your client by this:

```
io.connect('http://localhost:port/namespace');
```